Assign a value to cells according to contents of other cells
I have 2 tables - one is pre-poplated, and I want to assign values to a grid-type table according to the values of the first table.
It starts out looking like this

I want to use the values in columns 2 and 3 to populate the cells in the grid with what is in column 1 so it will look like this

I think I could do it with massive nested IFs in each cell of the grid but it seems like there should be a better way.
Is there a way to do it without having to use VBA (or something else)?
Thanks!
I did the simple proof of the upper left cell of the grid to be populated using
=IF(B1=E1,IF(C1=D2,A2,""),"")
but there are 30 combinations of what can be in Col 2 and Col 3 so the nesting is laborious.  (I hate matching parentheses! :) )

This may be useful

Yes, index() with match() and lots of examples from simple to advanced on here.

I don't see any reason why you are not able to use an XLOOKUP() or INDEX()+MATCH() function here: You could try these simple ways : =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH(1,($E2=$C$1:$C$6)*(F$1=$B$1:$B$6),0)),"") or =XLOOKUP(1,($E2=$C$1:$C$6)*(F$1=$B$1:$B$6),$A$1:$A$6,"")

Using the images shown in the original post assume that the input value P1 is in cell A2 and that the number 1 in the result column is in cell E2.
Paste the following formula in cell F2, drag the fill handle across to cell K2 and then, while cells F2:K2 are still selected, drag the fill handle down to cell K5.
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$1))/($B$2:$B$7=F$1)/($C$2:$C$7=$E2),1)),"")


Thanks for the advice.   I'll try these and see what happens then report back.

With this formula:
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$12:$H$17,MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",A1),"$",""),$I$12:$I$17&$J$12:$J$17,0)),"")

this is the result:

